# How to script a csv to file geodatabase tool?

Tags: python, enterprise-geodatabase, csv, file-geodatabase

I have many separate field data files in CSV format and I wish to automatically convert these CSV files into a geodatabase to be able to load them into a schema I created for them in my new ArcSDE enterprise database. The SDE version is 10.1. I am able to do this manually in ArcGIS but I have over 500 files to complete and so I do need a script will automate it for me.

I would be glad to have the output in a form of a feature class. I do not have an existing output dataset besides the ones I did manually, it needs to be created from scratch using the CSV files as input dataset.

Comment: More info please... What code have you got so far? What version of ArcGIS are you using? Or are you trying to load using the file geodatabase API via OGR? Your title states "file geodatabase", but the question body specifies SDE. Which is it?

Comment: More questions: Is the desired output a feature class or a standalone table? Does the output dataset already exist and you simply want to append rows into it, or must it be created from scratch? Posting a sample from your CSV file would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Please have a look at the [Copy Rows](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) geoprocessing tool.

The code can be as simple as the following:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CopyRows_management("C:/data/vegtable.csv", "C:/output/output.gdb/vegtable")
```